# What need to be defined as intent filter uri in AndroidManifest? My application domain, dynamic link domain or both?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, android-deep-link, android-app-links

Let say I have application with *https://myapplication.com* domain. I want my android application to be able to open links like *myapplication.com/users/12*.

So I've uploaded *https://myapplication.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json* and added next lines to AndroidManifest:

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data 
                 android:scheme="https"
                 android:host="myapplication.com"
                 android:path="/users/>
 </intent-filter>
```

Everything seems work fine, however I need to add Firebase Dynamic link support.
In firebase console i've created next dynamic link *myshort.link/RErvWrS6* which redirects to *myapplication.com/users/12*.

And my questions are:

- Should I add another Intent filter with *myshort.link* host?
- Do I need to add *users* suffix to firebase dynamic links and add it to new intent filter?
- assetlinks.json need to be available via both links:
  *https://myapplication.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json*
  *https://myshort.link/.well-known/assetlinks.json* ?

Comment: did you identify answers to your three questions? if so what were they?